# Mysql- How to get max date when the number of cases has peaked

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I am trying to do #8 on this problem set from sqlzoo (https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Window_LAG#LAG_using_a_JOIN).

The question is "For each country that has had at last 1000 new cases in a single day, show the date of the peak number of new cases."

The table covid gives the number of covid cases, deaths, and recoveries per day by country as so:

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|    Name     |              whn              | confirmed | deaths | recovered |
+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Afghanistan | Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT |         1 |      0 |         0 |
| Albania     | Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT |         0 |      0 |         0 |
| Algeria     | Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT |         1 |      0 |         0 |
+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Currently I have this code:

```
SELECT c.name, DATE_FORMAT(c.whn,'%Y-%m-%d') as this, d.peak
from ( select tw.name, max(tw.confirmed-lw.confirmed) as peak
FROM covid tw LEFT JOIN covid lw ON 
  DATE_ADD(lw.whn, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = tw.whn
   AND tw.name=lw.name
where tw.confirmed-lw.confirmed > 1000
group by tw.name) d
join covid as c
on d.name = c.name
group by name
```

which gives me each country, the date, and the peak number of cases. However, the date is showing the first day for each country when the cases are above a 1000. How would I get the date where there is the peak number of cases?

```
|  Name   |    this    | peak |
|---------|------------|------|
| Austria | 2020-03-26 | 1321 |
| Belarus | 2020-04-20 | 1485 |
| Belgium | 2020-03-26 | 2454 |
```

Comment: You should make the effort of providing sample data and desired results directly in your question, as tabular text or `create table`/ `insert` statements. Not everyone will be willing to read the entire quiz pages.

Comment: Your code and the dataset suggest BigQuery.  Why is the question tagged MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the number of *new* cases by comparing `confirmed` across subsequent days; for this, `lag()` comes handy:

```
select 
    t.*,
    confirmed - lag(confirmed, 1, 0) over(partition by name order by whn) new_cases
from mytable t
```

This assumes that each country has one record per day. You can then rank the records of each country by that, and filter on the top ranked day per country:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t*, 
        rank() over(partition by name order by new_cases desc) rn
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            confirmed - lag(confirmed, 1, 0) over(partition by name order by whn) new_cases
        from mytable t
    ) t
    where new_cases > 1000
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look good, but it works for MySQL. For some reasons, other answers didn't pass.

```
select t2.name,DATE_FORMAT(t3.whn,'%Y-%m-%d'),t2.peakNewCases
from
    (select a.name, max(a.confirmed-b.confirmed) as peakNewCases
     from covid a 
     left join covid b
     on DATE_ADD(b.whn, interval 1 day)=a.whn 
     and 
     a.name=b.name
     where a.confirmed-b.confirmed>999
     group by name
    ) t2 
join 
    (select name, whn, confirmed-lag(confirmed,1) over (partition by name order by confirmed) as peakNewCases
     from covid
    ) t3 
on t2.peakNewCases=t3.peakNewCases 
and 
t2.name=t3.name
order by t3.whn
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY peak) AS rank` to rank the number of new cases everday of each country and then select the ones that `rank = 1` in the outer query to find the peak. Here is my complete query:

```
SELECT name, date, peak FROM
 (SELECT name, date, peak, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY peak DESC) as rank
  FROM 
   (SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(whn,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
    confirmed - (LAG(confirmed, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY whn)) AS peak 
    FROM 
     covid)  
  TAB WHERE peak >= 1000)
TAB WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY date
```

It seems like the order of output needs to be adjusted to fit perfectly to the answer, but I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
   total_cases - LAG(total_cases,1) OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY date) 
   AS new_cases,
   total_cases,
   state,
   date
FROM statistics
```